# if else use in mysql where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have this query with inner join. Currently this returns data when `product_id` exists in the `coupon_restrict table`. 
What I want to do is that if `product_id` doen't event exist then it should return the data from coupon table.

```
SELECT c.public_private, c.coupon_code, c.coupon_amount, c.coupon_type, 
c.coupon_zone_restriction, c.coupon_expire_date, c.is_stash
FROM coupons c, 
coupon_restrict cr, 
products p
WHERE 
c.coupon_type = 'P' 
AND (c.public = 1 OR c.public_private = 1) 
AND c.coupon_id = cr.coupon_id 
AND DATEDIFF(c.coupon_expire_date, NOW()) > 0
AND cr.product_id IN (1808)
AND cr.product_id = p.products_id
AND p.products_quantity > 0
AND cr.coupon_restrict = 'N'
```

Comment: And what have you tried? You know how to tag it with left join which is what you need to do but you didn't try any. Show your effort. Remember that SO is not a free code service.

Comment: Stop using old-style `joins` where you separate table names with commas and specify the join criteria in the where clause!  These are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need left join for your `coupon_restrict` and `products` if you need the data from coupons table whether their association exists in other table or not

```
SELECT c.public_private, c.coupon_code, c.coupon_amount, c.coupon_type, 
c.coupon_zone_restriction, c.coupon_expire_date, c.is_stash
FROM coupons c
LEFT JOIN coupon_restrict cr ON c.coupon_id = cr.coupon_id  
                             AND cr.coupon_restrict = 'N'
                             AND cr.product_id IN (1808)
LEFT JOIN products p ON cr.product_id = p.products_id 
                     AND p.products_quantity > 0
WHERE c.coupon_type = 'P' 
AND (c.public = 1 OR c.public_private = 1) 
AND DATEDIFF(c.coupon_expire_date, NOW()) > 0
```

Also do move your where filters for joined tables in `on` clause